# Object property always returns undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have react component with constructor:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    console.log(props.user);
    console.log(props.user.email);
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
{"id":7,"email":"some@mail.ru","locale":"en","hp":100,"created_at":"2017-10-10T20:42:04.677Z","updated_at":"2017-10-10T21:35:22.297Z"}

undefined
```

Comment: try `props.user['email']`

Comment: @cfraser i provided output for the props.user, and it's an object. Read the question, please.

Comment: @xDreamCoding same

Comment: try using `this.props` in `your console.log`

Comment: It's possibly an issue of accessing properties of nested objects.  Can you first set a variable `user = props.user` and then try to access `user.email`?

Comment: @snapjs already tried that. Same result :(

Comment: @Src nothing seems to be wrong here. Any more code you can share? Only other thing I can think of is if `props.user` is not just an `Object` but a more specific superclass that may have a getter for `email` or may not contain an `email` property at all and is just spitting that out when stringified. Less likely would be that something may be writing to the `user` Object in between the execution of those two lines…though that would be incredibly unlucky.

Comment: `console.log({"id":7,"email":"some@mail.ru","locale":"en","hp":100,"created_at":"2017-10-10T20:42:04.677Z","updated_at":"2017-10-10T21:35:22.297Z"}.email);` runs fine. Please add more context.

Comment: Maybe it's another instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`props.user` is a JSON string and not a javascript object. You need to parse it first and then reach the child properties.

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    console.log(props.user);
    const user = JSON.parse(props.user);
    console.log(user.email);
}
```

Comment: It's probably not. Output: `SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 2 of the JSON data`

Comment: @Src: The output you are showing is how a string would be logged to the console. What does `typeof props.user` say?

Comment: @FelixKling My bad, js was cached. Yeah, it turns out to be a JSON object. And this is really strange, because `react-rails` should handle that. And if i'm not using explicitly `to_json` for an object on the back-end i can use it without parsing. But it should invoke to_json anyway, so what is the problem... ehh mistery. Thank you !